# Conditional locking based on value

Tags: c#

I am writing a web service that allows users to create jobs within the system. Each user has an allowance of the number of jobs they can create. I have a method which checks that the user has some remaining credits which looks like this:

```
private bool CheckRemainingCreditsForUser(string userId)
{
    lock(lockObj)
    {
       var user = GetUserFromDB(userId);
       if (user.RemaingCredit == 0) return false;
       RemoveOneCreditFromUser(user);
       SaveUserToDB(user);
    }
}
```

The problem I can see with this approach is that if multiple different users make a request at the same time they will only get processed one at a time which could cause performance issues to the client. Would it be possible to do something like this?

```
private bool CheckRemainingCreditsForUser(string userId)
{
    //If there is a current lock on the value of userId then wait 
    //If not get a lock on the value of userId
    var user = GetUserFromDB(userId);
    if (user.RemaingCredit == 0) return false;
    RemoveOneCreditFromUser(user);
    SaveUserToDB(user);
    //Release lock on the value of userId
}
```

This would mean that requests with different userIds could be processed at the same time, but requests with the same userId would have to wait for the previous request to finish

Comment: slightly off-topic but I don't really get the "lock on the value of userId" part.

Comment: Why would you need to lock in the first place? You dont have any shared resources that you might want to prevent simultaneous access to. As far as i see it, what you want to do kind of dublicates the functionality that your database has.

Comment: Sidenote not related to the question: method is called `Check`, which I expect to have no side effects. On the other hand, you can always write a stored procedure with: `UPDATE user ... WHERE credits > 1 and UserId = ...` and return the number of rows affected. This only locks a single row.

Comment: @Caramiriel I'm am current using MongoDB as the backing database so cannot create stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do that with a `Dictionary<string, object>`. To link a lockObject to every userId.

The problem would be cleaning up that Dictionary every so often.

But I would verify first that there really is a bottleneck here. Don't fix problems you don't have.

The alternative is to have a (optimistic) concurrency check in your db and just handle the (rare) conflict cases.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar but had the same concern about cleaning up and was wondering there was a more elegant solution

Comment: You can't (shouldn't) lock on the userId strings so the Dictionary is unavoidable. Up to a few 1000 users per server not a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of locking in every methods, why aren't you using a **Singleton** that will manage the *User*'s rights ?

It will be responsible from giving the remaining allowances AND manage them at the same time without loosing the thread-safe code.

By the way, a method named `CheckRemainingCreditsForUser` should not remove allowances since the name isn't implying it, you may be the only developer on this project but it won't hurt to make 2 methods to manage this for re-useability and code comprehension.

**EDIT :** And this object should also hold the *Users* dictionary

Comment: The problem for me with using a singleton and managing it all in memory is that I'm trying to make sure that if needed in the future the service could be spread across multiple servers and it wouldn't matter which server the request went to as the DB would be master

Comment: Well, for this specific case you should use a transaction system between the services and the DB host. A service ask for the right to submit a DB transaction and send it after receiving the acknowledgement from the DB host.